# Does Vulkan involve clustered computing?

Tags: cluster-computing, vulkan

We know Vulkan can utilize Multi-GPU resources well, but does Vulkan involve clustered computing (distributing work across many machines with one GPU, not one machine with multiple GPUs)?

Comment: Oh, I should change another expression.
Does Vulkan has any APIs do clustered computing?

Comment: Sorry for my misspelling. :)

Comment: If you can access the GPU from each machine as if the GPU belonged to that machine, there is no reason why not. This would be similar to multiple processes using the same GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the Vulkan [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/pdf/vkspec.pdf) explicitly mentions clustered computing, or explicitly disallows it. The documentation does refer to the 'host' frequently, with the connotation that execution occurs on a single physical box.

It is hard to imagine that a cluster execution environment would be viable for Vulkan, as it is meant as a high performance graphics API. The implications queue synchronization and memory transfer of GPUs/memory over a network would be an extreme bottleneck. The only situations which would make sense would be operations that do not need to be synchronized very often (for example, some very long computation done on the GPU). However, in that case, the synchronization of results could be implemented outside of Vulkan itself.